# UnitTests: how to test dependent methods where mocking is unfeasible?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I'm fairly new to UnitTesting and just encountered a situation I don't know how to handle and I'd appreciate any hints :)

The situation is as follows, imagine two methods:

```
// simple standalone method
public bool HelperMethod(string substr) {
    return substr.Equals("abc");
}

// complex method making (multiple) use of HelperMethod
public bool ActualMethod(string str) {

    for (var i=0; i<str.Length; i++) {
         var substr = str.Substring(i, 3);
         if (HelperMethod(substr))
             return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

*HelperMethod* functions without dependencies, *ActualMethod* however depends on *HelperMethod* and therefore its UnitTest will fail if *HelperMethod*'s one does.

Actually, if I'm not mistaken, this is where mocking/dependency injection should come to rescue.

But in this specific case, I'd like to test several (arbitrary large) edge-cases (which may not be necessary for the code above, but the actual *ActualMethod* implementation is a part of fairly complex syntax parser). Since *HelperMethod* is called multiple times in each *ActualMethod* call, I would have to mock hundreds of *HelperMethod* calls for my test which just seems unbearable (now just imagine the number of needed *HelperMethod* calls would be quadratic to the input..).

**My question is:** how could one elegantly test a method that delegates a huge number of calls to another method? Should I really mock all these delegate calls? Or am I maybe allowed to make the method test depend on the other method's test (sth. like *Assert(HelperMethodPassed)*? Or is there no way around changing the design of the implementation?

Unfortunately inlining *HelperMethod* in the *ActualMethod* isn't possible because other methods rely on it as well.

Thanks in advance, I'd really appreciate any help! :)

PS:
The project that is being tested is written in C# and I'm currently using the MSTest framework (but I'm open for switching to another framework if this solves the problematic).

**Edit:** explicitly marked *HelperMethod* and *ActualMethod* as public.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, if code is difficult to isolate for testing, it points to a design problem.

Since you're calling `HelperMethod` a bunch of times in the context of the method you're trying to test, it sounds like the problem is that `ActualMethod` is doing too much. You can make it more unit testable by breaking `ActualMethod` down into smaller methods that take the output of `HelperMethod` as a parameter, and then unit testing each of those individual methods.

Of course, you'll want to ensure that `HelperMethod` is unit tested as well!

As other folks have stated, if the `HelperMethod` is **private** and not used outside the class, then you can ignore the above advice and ensure that `HelperMethod` is tested by making sure that you cover every reasonable permutation of test cases via the public interface (e.g. `ActualMethod`). Fundamentally, though, if `HelperMethod` contains complex logic, it should probably be unit tested independently.

Comment: If you pick them apart at that point, then you just have to glue them back together somewhere else. I agree with your (implicit) statement that you have to design your abstractions for testing, but this seems like a 'how do I test my privates' problem.

Comment: Ahh, true. I was thinking of it as a public "helper" method, since the OP said that other methods rely on it. If it's private, then yeah. I'll update my answer accordingly. :)

Comment: I don't know if its private, but its being used that way. I don't think the OPs simplified example is all that helpful.

Comment: Agreed. Well, I updated my answer so it covers both bases. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Short summary: 1. difficult to isolate => rethink design 2. don't test private methods.

It turned out, that in this specific case I was able to simply make HelperMethod private. 

But what about the general case, where HelperMethod must be part of the public interface? Do you think one could say that this only arsises in bad design? Anyways, thanks for the discussion&help!

Comment: I woudln't worry too much about "bad design" vs "good design". Focus on, "Can I isolate this code and test it with as few dependencies as possible?". If `HelperMethod` was part of the public interface, my initial advice still applies: Test `HelperMethod`, then refactor `ActualMethod` into smaller, independently testable methods that rely on the results of calls to `HelperMethod`.

Comment: Ok I get your point. But as @RichMelton already said if you pick them apart one will probably have to glue them together aftewards. This may lead to the exact same problem just at a different point. But as I interpret this whole discussion, there doesn't exist a proper solution to this exact problem. One just needs to keep the possibility for isolation in mind during design and this problem will hopefully never occur. I think that's it, thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Answer (score 4):

If `MethodHelper` is an implementation detail and is consequently a private method in the same class as `ActualMethod` then I don't see a reason to test it seperately from `ActualMethod`. You should be able to achieve full coverage by testing `ActualMethod`.

Comment: I didn't know that private methods don't need to be unit tested! Thank you for that insight! Nice blog post from Peter Provost to back up this decision: http://www.peterprovost.org/blog/2012/05/31/my-take-on-unit-testing-private-methods 

Basically he comes to the conclusion that unit-testing private implementation details prevents the developer from free refactoring and should therefore be avoided just as you said.

Nonetheless it is assumed that *HelperMethod* from above is publicly accessible (edited the original post). But thanks for this hint!

Comment: You test private methods by testing the public methods :)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

- Test `HelperMethod` so that all possible invocations from `ActualMethod` are covered in the unit tests.
- Then assume that `HelperMethod` works and do not mock it, but use the actual implementation if you can guarantee that there aren't any side effects.

If the tests for `HelperMethod` fail, you can consider anything that `ActualMethod` does as undefined behavior, so it is not relevant if these tests pass or fail.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is what I was trying to circumvent. Making the ActualMethod test fail if the HelperMethod test fails may lead to confusion and inefficiency, e.g. if one encounters the error and starts debugging *ActualMethod* just in order to find out that it's *HelperMethod*'s fault.

Or do you think in this specific case (whole bunch of delegate calls where mocking is unfeasible), this kind test dependency is ok to have?

Comment: @AndréFreitag do not make the ActualMethod test fail, just ignore the results :)